# Editing the data in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

[image: The Error which i am getting]

The corresponding TS File  :

```
saveSegment(item) {
const body = {
  id: item.id,
  name: item.name,
  status: item.status,
  active: item.active,
  modifiedAt: item.modifiedAt,
  category: {
    id: item.category.id,
    name: item.category.name,
    active: item.category.active,
    status: item.category.status,
    modifiedAt: item.category.modifiedAt,
  },
  description: item.description,
  imagePath: item.imagePath,
  viewCount: item.viewCount,
  important: item.important
};
console.log('editable data', body);
this.http.put(this.mainUrl + item.id , body)
.subscribe((Response) => {
  alert('Updated successfully');
  this.route.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() =>
  this.route.navigate(['/blogger']));
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

The HTML File :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveSegment(item.id)">Save changes</button>
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong here,I am unable to save the datas to the API?
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change your button to this:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveSegment(item)">
  Save changes
</button>
```

Your `saveSegment` method is expecting an item, but you were passing just the `item.id`

Comment: I tried the above and i am getting HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "http://13.127.6.195:8080/api/blog/undefined", ok: false, …} in lin No:88, Which means the data is not getting updated in the API

Comment: thats a different issue, that you should try and debug. whats the log of >   console.log('editable data', body);. Ill suggest you either update your question to add this error or ask a new question

Comment: you can see by the address > 13.127.6.195:8080/api/blog/undefined .. that `item.id` that you append to `this.mainUrl` is undefined

Comment: In the console.log  i'm gettting the edited data,But That newly edited data is not pushing to API and hence i'm getting undefined error.